# Merge title and subtitle fields in bibliographic entries

Tags: biblatex, biber, pandoc-citeproc

I would like to merge all `title` and `subtitle` fields in a bib file into the field `title` with a custom separator. Is there a way to do this? (I know that `biber` has a tool mode that can be used for manipulating a source file. It is, for example, possible to resolve inheritances. But it would seem to me that merging two fields into one is not possible.)

Background: I sometimes use my bib file with `pandoc`. `Pandoc` merges the fields `title` and `subtitle`, but it uses a colon as a separator, which is rather unusual in German.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <output_align>true</output_align>
  <output_fieldcase>lower</output_fieldcase>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" level="user">
      <map map_overwrite="1">
        <map_step map_field_source="subtitle" map_final="1"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="title" map_field_value=". " map_append="1"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="title" map_origfieldval="1" map_append="1"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="subtitle" map_null="1"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

in a file called `mergesubtitle.conf` into the same directory as your `.bib` file.

Then call Biber with

```
biber --tool --configfile=mergesubtitle.conf <yourbibfile.bib>
```

If

```
@book{elk,
  author = {Anne Elk},
  title = {On the Theory of Brontosauruses},
  subtitle = {Really Interesting Dinosaurs},
  date = {1970},
  publisher = {Monthy Press},
  location = {London},
}
```

is saved as `brontos.bib`, the call `biber --tool --configfile=mergesubtitle.conf brontos.bib` will result in a file called `brontos_bibertool.bib` with the contents

```
@book{elk,
  author    = {Elk, Anne},
  location  = {London},
  publisher = {Monthy Press},
  date      = {1970},
  title     = {On the Theory of Brontosauruses. Really Interesting Dinosaurs},
}
```

being placed in the same directory.